# How to change from Win-10 To Win-11 in New Workstation

Tags: windows, windows-10

I am getting a new Dell workstation.

In OS choice I have to select one of two options.

(1) Windows 10 Pro for Workstations (6 cores, Includes Windows 11 Pro License) English

(2) Windows -11

I have never used any of them. So I am inclined to choose Win-10 to see what it is like.

My question is what does option 1 mean ? Do I get a key for Win-11 ?

I know I will get Win-10 in a single 512GB NVMe Partition.

(1) If I want to then Limit Win-10 partition to 220 GB, how would I do that so that I can have two more partitions for data in that NVME 512GB SSD with Win-10 ?

(2) If I want to try or switch to Win-11, how would I do that ?

(3) I am also getting 2nd M.2 NVME 512GB SSD. Can I install Win-11 in that SSD & then remove Win-10 SSD & place Win-11 SSD & boot & try Win-11 that way ? If so how ?

(4) Can I dual boot Win-10 & Win-11 ? If so how & how much space will be needed for both OS ?

I would really appreciate all the help.

Thank You

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Have you tried to google these questions? How far did you get? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Do not try to dual boot both operating systems. Waste of time and this forum is littered with broken systems. Install Windows 11 and learn how it works and adapt to it.

Comment: Pro is always better than non-pro. This obviously depends on your needs. You haven't specified Pro on the Windows 11 option. If Windows 11 offer is not pro, then i would suggest going with Windows 10 Pro, because it's free to upgrade.. and the upgrade path will be to Windows 11 PRO.

Comment: The problem here is that this is a software recommendation of sorts and you are not going to get much better than opinion.  I myself hate the pants off of Windows 11.  @John and MANY others don't hate it.. we are all smart.  It is a matter of opinion.  Technically, this question should be shut down but because of the pro-vs-nonpro possibility I am not going to mess with that.

Comment: They offer Pro Versions for both OS. Where it gets very technical is that besides Pro, it has to be a Workstation version. It also gets very technical because I want to try installing Win-11 on a separate SSD & then remove the Win-10 SSD & try Win-11 SSD. Is that possible or it will create any problems ? Also where can I download Win-11 Pro for Workstation ? https://imgur.com/K4peCEH